# Recover file from a field name oid

Tags: postgresql

I have little doubt, I have a field of type **oid** in my database I'm saving the text files, I wonder if I can somehow retrieve the name with which you saved the file. Do not know if in some way to do so successfully *lo_export* or another method.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PostgreSQL does not create a separate file for each large object stored in the database; a fairly normal heap table with btree index is used.  So large objects are broken into smaller pieces for easier space management by the database, and intermingled within the 1GB segment files used by that table.

Taking a quick peek at the pg_class table, I see an entry for pg_largeobject, which I think is where all objects stored with the "lo" large object feature are stored.  On my system I see a relfilenode of 11869, which means that the initial file for storing data would be 11869 and subsequent files would be 11869.1, 11869.2, etc.  I don't know whether there is any way for the relfilenode to be reassigned for large objects, but you should probably check your pg_class entry to be sure.

Generally, large objects stored in the database should not be accessed except through the "lo" functions provided.  If you want separate files and the ability to access them directly, you should probably save them directly to disk and store the filename or a URI.  You could save them to disk from inside a PostgreSQL function, or externally.

Comment: Thanks for the reply kgrittn, I will try and tell you depends on the outcome I did.